# Reload or rebind tab content on tab click or tab change with AJAX issues

Tags: asp.net, ajax, tabs, telerik, radgrid

I have a rad tab strip. It has 3 tabs. On selecting a tab it is doing postback. I have a TabClick event. On this event I check if it is 2nd tab then i refresh the datasource for a radgrid within this 2nd tab. I tried to ajaxify it by

```
 <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="rtsINSP">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="rmpMain" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
```

where rtsINSP is my RadTabStrip and rmpMain is the RadMultiPage within which I have 3 tabs(or telerik radpageviews). When I do that it works by NOT showing the postback but the selected tab always shows up as the 1st one. I mean I selected tab 2, it shows content for tab 2, but the selected tab is still tab 1. If i select 3, shows the contents on 3rd tab but still shows the selected tab on top as 1st tab. How can I get to show the content and selected tab as the one I select.
If you need more info, please ask. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add the tabstrip itself as an updated control in this setup so it gets updated after the postback:

```
 <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="rtsINSP">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="rtsINSP" />
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="rmpMain" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
```